# Radios button in form arrays

Tags: forms

How can i check which radio button has been checked from a list of radio buttons ? Is there any key in the form array which holds the checked radio ?

I am using an ajax call for a bunch of radios buttons and i would like to do some "checking"  only if the right radio button was selected.

As an alternative , how can i append the "#ajax" parameter to only one radio button in a list of radio buttons ?

Comment: Tell us what your trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlexGill was i clear enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the element's value in `$form_state['values']`. Add the full parameter list ($form, &$form_state) to the form builder function.

For example:
`function mymodule_something_form($form, &$form_state) {`